# App using foregroundservices causes package file invalid message only in release mode

Tags: android

I developed an app for reading data via classic bluetooth (4.0 ) using foregroundservices. Every 5 seconds I read the data coming from bluetooth and send this data to a server itself, using HttpURLConnection inside an AsyncTask.
So the working cycle is as follows:
the user chooses the desired device, connects to it and then the service that is reading the data is started. From then on every 5 seconds I send the data to the dedicated server.
In debug mode via android studio, no errors occurred and the app worked normally.
When generating the app in debug mode and trying to install it through the file manager, it is possible to install normally.
When generating the app in release mode and trying to install it through the file manager, a message is displayed that the app is dangerous and it is not possible to complete the installation.
On android 10 , the dangerous app message allows me to install but on android 11 and above it is not possible to install at all.

Permissions used in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

Gradle.file - build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "33.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "construtec.com.br.monitoramentomobilev1e"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            def project = "MonitoramentoMobile_v1e"

            def newApkName = project + ".apk"
         
            outputFileName = new File(newApkName)
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

I ask for the following permissions via code:

```
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE , ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION , ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION INTERNET
```

What could be considered dangerous for Google Protect to block installation ?

PS : If necessary I can post the codes in question.

I would like to understand what could cause the problem in question in release mode, since in debug mode it seems to have no problem with the installation.

Comment: May you share with us your gradle file

Comment: @Mouaad Abdelghafour AITALI - Added Gradle build file. I hope this help and if more code are necessary , please tell me. Thanks